# Accessing positions in a Ziplist

Tags: list, haskell, types

I just found out that  the `!!` operator is for lists only:

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

So I searched for alternatives at hoogle:

- [`Foldable f => f a -> Int -> a`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Foldable%20f%20%3D%3E%20f%20a%20-%3E%20Int%20-%3E%20a)
- [`ZipList a -> Int -> a`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=ZipList%20a%20-%3E%20Int%20-%3E%20a)

I am very surprised not to have found one!

So I ask:

1. What is the way to access a ziplist by index without converting it back to list?
2. What hoogle search would have found it

Of course, answering 1 goes a long way towards answering 2, because I'd have the type signature

Comment: A ziplist is essentially the same thing as a list, and converting it to a list is a very cheap operation. It is just the Applicative instance that differs. You could define: `at zl n = let xs = getZipList zl in xs !! n` ; but if your intention is to have indexing as the main access mode, it is probably more efficient to convert the (zip)list into a Vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) is a [`newtype`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-680004.2), so there is *no* conversion. It just is that same list.

```
newtype ZipList a = ZipList { getZipList :: [a] }
```

As the Report states in [section 4.2.3 Datatype Renamings](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-680004.2),

> A declaration of the form *newtype cx => T u1 … uk = N t* introduces a new type whose representation **is the same** as an existing type.

(emphasis mine). When the code runs, the `ZipList` tag isn't there at all.  Thus,

- [`getZipList`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=ZipList%20a%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D) is a *zero* *cost* *no-op*.

As an illustration, treating a `ZipList Int` value as a `[Int]` value is perfectly fine. Observe:

```
GHCi> coerce (ZipList [1,2,3] :: ZipList Int) :: [Int]
[1,2,3]
it :: [Int]
```

Thus the data constructor `ZipList` is just a compile-time tag with which we declare our intentions as to which applicative implementation is to be used. Specifically, the zipping one, not the nested loops one (of the regular `[]`).

As to the `!!` itself, it should be avoided. Repeated calls to it with growing index values will cause quadratic behavior. Any number of higher-order functions can be used instead, or a direct recursion can be coded if needed, processing a list's elements one by one without re-tracing the list from the start anew for each element.